# How would you (re)implement iterate in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, loops, combinators

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

(As you probably know) `iterate` is a function that takes a function and starting value. Then it applies the function to the starting value, then it applies the same function to the last result, and so on.

```
Prelude> take 5 $ iterate (^2) 2
[2,4,16,256,65536]
Prelude>
```

The result is an infinite list. (that's why I use `take`). 
My question how would you implement your own `iterate'` function in Haskell, using only the basics (`(:)` `(++)` lambdas, pattern mataching, guards, etc.) ?

(Haskell beginner here)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, *iterate* constructs an infinite list of values *a* incremented by *f*. So I would start by writing a function that prepended some value *a* to the list constructed by recursively calling iterate with *f a*:

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f a = a : iterate f (f a)
```

Thanks to lazy evaluation, only that portion of the constructed list necessary to compute the value of my function will be evaluated.

Comment: This looks like the a variation of the "fix" definition "fix f = f (fix f)" similar to ..."iterate f (f a)" you could use fix to define iterate:
"iterate f a = fix (\r x -> x:r (f x) ) a" not that its any better, just thought id say :)

Answer (score 15):

Also note that you can find concise definitions for the range of basic Haskell functions in the report's [Standard Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html).

Reading through this list of straightforward definitions that essentially bootstrap a rich library out of raw primitives can be very educational and eye-opening in terms of providing a window onto the "haskell way".

I remember a very early aha moment on reading: `data  Bool  =  False | True`.